certbot Could not automatically find a matching server block for subdom.mydom.com. Set the `server_name` directive
Certbot is not able to install the certificate for a subdomain nginx config.
It says that no matching server_name directive is set, although it is set.
1) My Nginx config:
server {

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name subdom.mydom.com, www.subdom.mydom.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
    }

    # Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/subdom.mydom.com_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/subdom.mydom.com_log;
}

It's a reverse proxy to an apache2 instance.
2)
sudo ngnix -t says:
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

3) The config is enabled with a symbolic link in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
4) The reverse proxy redirect to apache2 virtual host and the virtual host config are working, since the site is perfectly reachable over HTTP, with the expected nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu) value set to the response headers Server field.
5) With:
certbot --nginx -d subdom.mydom.com -d www.subdom.mydom.com

certbot creates the certificates but is not able to generate the respective 443 server block.
Could not automatically find a matching server block for subdom.mydom.com. Set the `server_name` directive to use the Nginx installer.
However the server_name directive is already set.
I use the exact same setup (subdomain, nginx reverse proxy, apache2 virtual host, etc) on another project, which works absolutely flawless. In fact the http server block is actually a copy of the other working project, with adjusted server_names and log paths, of course. However the working one I set up a couple of years ago and I can't recall weather or not there were additional steps involved.
What am I missing out on? How do I get this working?

You have a , in your server_name statement. It should be a space separated list, no commas.

I removed the commas but still get the same error. As I said, I use the exact same config, same structure, same syntax for another project, also with commas in the server_name directive and that works without any problem.

I got this solved now.
I managed to get it working by generating the certificate with --cert-only and with some research I was able to get the certbot generated server block and adjust the rest to my needs.
The certbot command:
certbot --cert-name mydom.com -d subdom.mydom.com -d www.subdom.mydom.com

My working Nginx conf now looks like this:
server {
    server_name subdom.mydom.com www.subdom.mydom.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/subdom.mydom.com.access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/subdom.mydom.com.error_log;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydom.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydom.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.subdom.mydom.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = subdom.mydom.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name subdom.mydom www.subdom.mydom.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

